# Is there a way to run tests in Django without creating database?

Tags: python, django, testing

I'm getting an error in a simple functional test that I suspect is related to creating a large database. The error is

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

It takes sometime until database is created and to test if the error is related to this, I would run the test without creating the test database.

Is it possible to run tests with `python manage.py test functional_test.py` skipping the database creation?

Comment: `pytest-django` is often a more flexible way to run tests (https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is way to run tests without destroying and recreating database:

```
python manage.py test -k
```

from `python manage.py test --help`

> -k, --keepdb          Preserves the test DB between runs.

the database will not be destroyed and migrated at each test run. You can see better progress with `-v 3`.

You cannot run tests without creating and using the database. Hope `-k` helps.

Comment: Thanks @Krystofee, in fact the problem was a mistake made by myself, a bug in the test code. But as your tip solves at least by now the problem with the long taking test, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Is there a way to run Django tests **without any DB**? I need pure unit tests and I'd prefer running these tests before even the initial migration's done. "Unit tests" smells bad if they relay on a DB. I tried "NoDBRunner" hack ... but my test failed if I pointed Django to non-existing DB.